# Strings and arithmetic operations

Tags: string, numbers, operation

people. Can you please tell me how can I turn a string into arithmetic operation.

For example:

```
string_with_operation = "(23 + 3) / 4"

usual_operation = (23 + 3) / 4
```

I want a `string_with_operation` to be the same as `usual_operation`

I tried turn `string_with_operation` into an integer and a float but as expected it caused an error.

Comment: This question is not answerable without specifying the programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python can use eval() function

```
string_with_operation = "(23 + 3) / 4"

result = eval(string_with_operation)

print(result)
```

This is a good tutorial
[https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20built,it%20as%20a%20Python%20expression](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20built,it%20as%20a%20Python%20expression).

Comment: documentation
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which programming language you're using but in python, there's [eval](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eval-in-python/) can help you.

here's the example you mentioned in action:

```
string_with_operation = "(23 + 3) / 4"

try:
    result = eval(string_with_operation)
    print(result)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
```

However, be careful when using `eval()` with untrusted input, as it can execute arbitrary code and pose security risks. If the input is not under your control, consider alternative ways to parse and evaluate expressions more safely.